# Google App Engine Datastore integration testing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, integration-testing

I would like to write some integration tests for my Google App Engine REST server.

My current setup is that I run Rest-Assured integration tests against my locally running GAE environment. This works flawlessly for simple calls returning json.

I want to get a step further and before I run a Rest-Assured IT I want to clear the datastore and pre-fill it with some test data.

Is it possible to interact with the same datastore (from integration test) then the local app is running? Note I'm running tests from both Eclipse or mvn test.

I already tried the LocalServiceTestHelper

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
    new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
```

but that does not seem to connect to same datastore, which also makes sense as it is meant for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that test you are doing is just a Unit Test (JUnit) thus what you need is a integration test like using Arquillian.

Using GAE Arquillian testing is quite simple, you just need to use the GAE Arquillian container developed and maintained by RedHat CapeDwarf team:

https://github.com/alesj/arquillian-container-gae

Here is an example usage: https://github.com/alesj/arquillian-container-gae/blob/master/gae-embedded/src/test/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/appengine/embedded/AppEngineEmbeddedClientTestCase.java

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your test fixtures as a [separate module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/). In that module write a set of ReST handlers that setup and teardown your test data. Then, in your tests invoke those handlers via http.

Beware that there is a slight delay for new records to show in a cloud datastore query, depending on what you are doing you may need to take this into consideration in your test code.